# Twitter client for Linux that doesn't break?

Tags: linux, twitter

I used 2 programs:

- Choqok
- tircd

both of them fail every so often - either crashing and requiring re-launch (tircd), or they for some reason stop to authenticate properly (Choqok).

Is there any client that **just works**?

Comment: Does it have to be a native app? I'm using Echofon on Firefox (on Linux)

Comment: I try not to keep webbrowser running all the time. So firefox based are rather no-go for me.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [this](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/overview-twitter-clients-linux) article.  It has a great list of twitter clients for linux.  Also, [TweetDeck](http://tweetdeck.com) (which runs on adobe air) seems to be a favorite.  A [question already asked](https://superuser.com/questions/2610/best-twitter-client-for-linux) on Super User might be helpful.

Comment: TweetDeck doesn't work for me (I guess because of 64bit OS) :(

Comment: TweetDeck works fine on 64 bit Linux.

Comment: GodEater: didn't work for me. Straight build from arch yaourt.

Comment: Maybe you should try Gwibber?

Comment: @depesz Do you have Adobe Air installed?

Comment: ephilip: yes. I.e. I had, but now I uninstalled it since twitterdeck didn't work.

Comment: Hmm... Try one of the other clients